# Issue Creating Epic in Jira Using Python

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to create an Epic issue in Jira using Python and the Jira API. Here's the code I'm using:

```
def establish_jira_connection(username, password, server_url):
    options = {'server': server_url}

    try:
        jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=(username, password))
        print("OK Jira")
        return jira
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"NG connectionJira: {e}")
        return None

def create_epic(jira, proj_key, epic_summary, epic_description):
    try:
        epic = jira.create_issue(
            project=proj_key,
            summary=epic_summary,
            description=epic_description,
            ssuetype={'name': 'Epic'})
        return epic.key
    except Exception as e:
        return None

username = input(" ")
password = getpass(" ")
server_url = "https://j.server.com"
proj_key = input(" ")
epic_summary = input(" ")
epic_description = input(" ")
jira = establish_jira_connection(username, password, server_url)
epic_key = create_epic(jira, proj_key, epic_summary, epic_description)`
```

However, when I run this code, I'm getting the following error:

```
JiraError HTTP 400 url: https://j.server.com/rest/api/2/issue
response text = {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"customfield_10011":"Field 'customfield_10011' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown."}}
```

Updated log of error use:

```
traceback.print_exc()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gvirbickas/PycharmProjects/task-jira-csv/main.py", line 27, in create_epic
    epic = jira.create_issue(
  File "/home/gvirbickas/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/task-jira-csv-JILiLnEB-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jira/client.py", line 1515, in create_issue
    r = self._session.post(url, data=json.dumps(data))
  File "/home/gvirbickas/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/task-jira-csv-JILiLnEB-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 637, in post
HTTP 400 url: https://j.server.com/rest/api/2/issue
    
    response headers = {'server': 'nginx/1.18.0', 'date': 'Sat, 14 Oct 2023 16:21:15 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'x-arequestid': '1161x85662906x2', 'x-asessionid': '1b4ke5p', 'x-anodeid': 'node1', 'referrer-policy': 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin', 'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'content-security-policy': 'sandbox', 'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000', 'x-seraph-loginreason': 'OK', 'x-ausername': 'g.virbickas', 'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, no-transform', 'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'vary': 'User-Agent'}
    response text = {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"customfield_10104":"Epic Name  обязательно."}}
    return self.request("POST", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gvirbickas/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/task-jira-csv-JILiLnEB-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jira/resilientsession.py", line 246, in request
    elif raise_on_error(response, **processed_kwargs):
  File "/home/gvirbickas/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/task-jira-csv-JILiLnEB-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jira/resilientsession.py", line 71, in raise_on_error
    raise JIRAError(
jira.exceptions.JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 400 url: https://j.server.com/rest/api/2/issue
    
    response headers = {'server': 'nginx/1.18.0', 'date': 'Sat, 14 Oct 2023 16:21:15 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'x-arequestid': '1161x85662906x2', 'x-asessionid': '1b4ke5p', 'x-anodeid': 'node1', 'referrer-policy': 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin', 'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'content-security-policy': 'sandbox', 'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000', 'x-seraph-loginreason': 'OK', 'x-ausername': 'g.virbickas', 'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, no-transform', 'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'vary': 'User-Agent'}
    response text = {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"customfield_10104":"Epic Name  necessarily."}}
```

I've tried changing the task type, and everything works, but when I try to create an Epic, I encounter this error with the custom field. I'm passing all the necessary parameters to the function. Can someone help me understand and resolve this issue?

Decided, assigned a name to a specific jira id:

```
def create_epic(jira, proj_key, epic_summary, epic_description):
    try:
        epic = jira.create_issue(
            project=proj_key,
            summary=epic_summary,
            description=epic_description,
            customfield_10104=epic_summary,
            issuetype={'name': 'Epic'}
        )
        return epic.key
    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()
        return None
```

Comment: Actually, I am a little bit late here. But assuming that customfield_10104 is actually the summary, then the error usually means that in the epic definition in Jira you did not include the summary field. Have a look at the definition of epic and make sure all fields are included which you want to set.